# Implementing soap in javascript only environment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, soap, ember.js

I am trying to use soap as the backend services and provide data for my app.

My question is if we only use javascript framework (ex: Ember, Angular) without server side languages (ex: php)

Is that possible to implement it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: yeah, i've done webDAV back in the day. you just need to template up some ajax responses and dust off your XML dom skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create SOAP services using javascript framework without using any server side languages. It is only possible to access SOAP WSDL from java script. 
Here goes the example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function soap() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://testSoapURL.com/', true);

        // build SOAP request
        var service =
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
            '<soapenv:Envelope ' + 
                'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
                'xmlns:api="http://127.0.0.1/Integrics/Enswitch/API" ' +
                'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
                'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                '<soapenv:Body>' +
                '<api:some_api_callsoapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +
                        '<username xsi:type="xsd:string">login_uName</username>' +
                        '<password xsi:type="xsd:string">pass</password>' +
                    '</api:some_api_call>' +
                '</soapenv:Body>' +
            '</soapenv:Envelope>';

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                    alert('done check the response');
                }
            }
        }
        // Send the POST request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        xmlhttp.send(service);
        //Now send the request        
    }
</script>
```